# Add text over bars in ggplot2 when using fill aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to place `*` above some bars in my bar plot. This would be straightforward if I was not using the `fill` aesthetic, but with it, I cannot figure out how to place stars over the bars, rather than the x-axis ticks.

I have tried to use `geom_text`, and was unsuccessful.  I see that I can add them manually using `annotate`, but this is an inelegant solution.

Here is a minimal example of the dataset and plot I would like to add `*` to:

```
df <- data.frame(age = c('year1', 'year1', 'year2', 'year2'),
                 category = c('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat2'),
                 value = 1:4,
                 star = c("", "*", "", "")
)

g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(category, proportion, fill = age))
g <- g + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
g
```

[image]

How can I add the `*` from my data set in the `star` column over the corresponding bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this approach using `geom_text()` in dodge style:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(age = c('year1', 'year1', 'year2', 'year2'),
                 category = c('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat2'),
                 value = 1:4,
                 star = c("", "*", "", "")
)
#Plot
g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(category, value, fill = age,label=star))
g <- g + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
g <- g + geom_text(position = position_dodge(0.9),vjust=-0.5)
g
```

Output:

[image]

Let me know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: How did you you know to choose the value 0.9 for position_dodge?  The example here is a minimal example of a much more complicated plot—and it (surprisingly to me) worked for that one as well.  Also, I thought vjust was only defined for the interval [0,1]; can you provide some intuition about -0.5?

Comment: @BioBroo It is the custom to use 0.9 for placing labels correctly :) Also for vjust you can set negative or positive values. It depends of how nice you want the plot!